# Having one request object as a Method Signature parameter, which constitute all the required parameters

Tags: java

A method signature is part of the method declaration. It is the combination of the method name and the parameter list.

So instead of specifying a list of parameters, I just want to pass a request object which constitute all the parameters. It might not be true for all the methods, but want to try wherever it is possible.

Say for example

```
public void setMapReference(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
{
  //method code
}
```

can also be written as

```
public void setMapReference(Point point)
{
  //method code
}
```

---

```
class Point {
  int xCoordinate;
  int yCoordinate;
  boolean isValidPoint();
}
```

---

But the caller may confuse as he is not aware of the parameters..!!

Is it a good practice???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't do it "wherever it is possible" - but it's often a good idea, yes. Basically, ask yourself whether the parameters themselves constitute a coherent single entity: does it make sense to lump them together and think of them as a single "thing"? If so, encapsulating them sounds like a good idea. It's even better if there's obvious behaviour which that "thing" could take responsibility for, to avoid that code living in a class which already has other responsibilities.

EDIT: Note that I *wouldn't* let the `Point` type have package-access fields as you've shown: I'd make them private fields with properties, as normal. I'd try to make it immutable if possible.

Comment: Yeah, But the problem is...If I encapsulate all the parameters in the request object, then if I add any attribute to the request object(when needed), The callers of the method don't aware of the change, and not able to depict the problem as a compile time error. And the error will be promted at rum time.

Comment: @Pradeep: If you make all the mandatory values in the "request object" required as part of that object's constructor, then it will break the callers as you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only 2 parameters, leave it alone. Object parameter may cause **complex**, maybe you even need defensive copy for object parameter.

On other hand, most programmer couldn't remember parameters more than **3**, if there are same data types in parameters, it's worse and error prone for programmers. In this case, using object parameter is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers to the question [Building big, immutable objects without using constructors having long parameter lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848938/building-big-immutable-objects-without-using-constructors-having-long-parameter) are probably relevant here also (it doesn't really matter if you're dealing with methods or constructors, a constructor is just a special method, after all).